# ImageIO NullPointerException on server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, nullpointerexception, javax.imageio

I am getting a `NullPointerException` when I run my Java Servlet.

Here's my code:

```
out.println("<image>");
int BI_WIDTH = 1000;
int BI_HEIGHT = 1400;
BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(BI_WIDTH, BI_HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics2D g2d = bImage.createGraphics();
g2d.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
g2d.clearRect(0, 0, BI_WIDTH, BI_HEIGHT);
g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
BasicStroke bs = new BasicStroke(10);
g2d.setStroke(bs);
g2d.drawLine(30, 30, 800, 30);
//out.println("<status ref=\"done\" />");
//out.println("<status ref=\"" + bImage.getWidth() + "x" + bImage.getHeight() + "\" />");
out.println("<status ref=\"" + bImage.getWidth() + "x" + bImage.getHeight() + "\" />");

try {
    ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", new File("C:\\test.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    out.println("<status ref=\"" + e +"\" />");
}
out.println("</image>");
```

Here is the error I am getting from Tomcat:

```
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1538)
SendBasicReport.doGet(SendBasicReport.java:62)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Comment: are you sure the test.jpg you are trying to read is accessible/exist in server context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that `"C:\"` does not exist on your server, or that it is not accessible or writable from the web server.

Or, it could be that the format you want is really `"jpeg"` and not `"jpg"`.

The other parameters sent to `ImageIO.write` looks fine.

Comment: C:\ does exist and it is accessible I know this because I have a separate servlet that accesses a file "C:\Dessert.jpg" and it works fine

Comment: @LwaziPrusent Reading and writing in't the same thing, and may need different access rights.

Comment: `java.io.File` has `canRead()`, `canWrite()` and `canExecute()` methods that should be able to tell.

Comment: thank you, I changed file location and now it works fine. I feel a little silly, I should have tried that to begin with.

Comment: @LwaziPrusent Well, the exception message from ImageIO wasn't really helpful, so you can always blame Oracle.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its a bug in JDK7 not checking if the [stream is null](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/imageio/ImageIO.java#1538). Most likely its cause 
it did not find a proper [SPI for that image format](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/imageio/ImageIO.java#) or your missing some jars.

Regardless of whether the format (`jpg`) is (in)correct or missing jars it should not throw a NPE [so you should go file this as a bug](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/web/bugzilla.html) (doorknob ... whoever smelt it delt it :) ).

Comment: Thanks I will do just that, so do you think it will work if I install a new JDK

Comment: I certainly think this is a bug too. What JRE version is used? Using a different JDK probably won't fix it, but better show the real problem.